# Is it correct to use attributes in pipe methods?

Tags: python, named-pipes

In the following code section we have a source process that transmits information by reading elements from a tuple and writing the corresponding elements one by one on an anonynous pipe.
A second process plays the role of transformer process, i.e. reads what the source process writes in the anonymous pipe, tokenizes (distinguishes words based on white spaces) messages and writes the result in a FIFO (aka named pipe).. I wanted to ask, is it correct that I have received_messages as attribute in the transformer process, or should the transformer process have no attributes?

I tried this code :

```
def source_process():
   received_messages = []
   p = os.pipe() #p[0] is the reader and p[1] is the writer in the returned tuple of os.pipe()
   if not p:
       print ("pipe call!")
       os.close(p[0])
       os.close(p[1])
       os._exit(1)
   pid = os.fork()
   if pid == -1:
       print (os.strerror("fork call"))
       os.close(p)
       os._exit(1)
   elif pid == 0: #child process
       os.close (p[0]) # child does not read because here we close p[0]
       os.write (p[1], MESSAGES[0].encode()) # encode for converting strings to bytes
       os.write (p[1], MESSAGES[1].encode())
       os.write (p[1], MESSAGES[2].encode())
       os.write (p[1], MESSAGES[3].encode())
       os.close(p[1])
   else: # if the code reaches this line pid!=0 and thus we are in the parent process
       os.close(p[1])  # parent does not write because here we close p[1]
       for message in MESSAGES:
         read_message = os.read(p[0], len(message));
         received_messages.append(read_message.decode())
       os.wait()
       os.close(p[0])
   return received_messages

def transformer_process(received_messages):
 messages_splited=[]
 for received_message in received_messages:
   word=received_message.strip().split()
   messages_splited.append(word)
 try:
       # Open the named pipe for writing
       with open(fifoname, 'w') as pipeout:
           for message_splited in messages_splited:
               # Write each tokenized word separately to the named pipe
               for word in message_splited:
                   pipeout.write(word + '\n')
 except Exception as e:
       print(f"Error in child process: {e}")
 finally:
       os._exit(0)    
   
 return messages_splited
```

I'm not asking for a solution just tell me if it is correct or should I change it

Comment: Having `received_messages` as a parameter (not attribute) is not a problem. However, you are receiving the whole set of messages and processing them together. I believe the spirit of this exercise is to transform the messages in parallel, as they come in the pipe. In that case, either you pass the pipe itself (`p[0]`) to the transformer and do the decoding inside it, or you create an intermediate iterator that passes the messages one by one using the `yield` keyword.

Comment: It is also "cheating" to assume that `MESSAGES` is available to both the sender and the receiver. The receiving process should be able to receive arbitrary messages from the sender. You will need some communication protocol to define the message length and how to signal the end of the transmission.